# how to give write permission to a folder

Tags: elasticsearch, command-line, permissions, chmod

I have a user elasticsearch and I want to give it permission to write to the folder

```
/var/lib/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/nodes/0/indices/pGmjsSJHRAiMUC5paYfjag/0
```

So I did

```
chmod 777 /var/lib/elasticsearch/elasticsearch
```

but I still get an error?

```
failed to write in data directory [/var/lib/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/nodes/0/indices/pGmjsSJHRAiMUC5paYfjag/0] write permission is required
```

Comment: You should rather change the owner of `/var/lib/elasticsearch` to `elasticsearch:elasticsearch`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding -R will recursively change the permissions

```
chmod -R 777 <path>
```